# Android GCM is not working properly in smartphones with auto-start feature (e.g. Xiaomi)

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

There is an auto-start permission in some Xiaomi and Lenovo android phones which, if not granted, does not let the app receive GCM notifications if app is not in memory i.e. swiped away from recent apps section. (and that is not the problem)

Now, if I start a chat app (e.g. whatsapp and others) in the phone whose auto-start permission is set to false, it will start showing all the notifications that couldn't be delivered earlier as it doesn't have permission. (which is great)

My question is - Is it GCM's responsibility deliver those messages or these app are doing something else e.g. an API call to the server when they notice that messages/notifications couldn't get delivered first time?

**Android Manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.package.name">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />

<permission
    android:name="${manifestApplicationId}.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="${manifestApplicationId}.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<application
    android:name=".App"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">


    <activity
        android:name=".ui.activities.MapActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:exported="true"
        android:parentActivityName=".ui.activities.SupportChatActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden">

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".ui.activities.SupportChatActivity" />

    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".ui.activities.SupportChatActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

            <category android:name="${manifestApplicationId}" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service
        android:name=".services.GcmBroadcastReceiverService"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <service
        android:name=".services.GcmIDListenerService"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

</application>

</manifest>
```

**GCMBroadcastReceiverService.java**

```
public class GcmBroadcastReceiverService extends GcmListenerService {

private static final String TAG = "MyGcmListenerService";
private NotificationManager notificationManager;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
}


// [START receive_message]

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {


    /*String message = data.getString("message");
    Log.d(TAG, "From: " + from);
    Log.d(TAG, "Message: " + message);

    Log.d("GCM", "GCM recvd");

    // Do whatever you want with received message
    }
}
```

**Additional points:**

Everything is working as I want if auto-start is turned on for the app.

Server response is - success.

Testing with adb shell has the same behavior.

Everything is working in smartphones that doesn't have auto-start feature.

**EDIT:**

This is what log shows-

a) When I use this command-

adb shell am broadcast -a com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION -n com.packagename.debug/.GcmBroadcastReceiver --es "data.alert" "foo"

```
01-13 11:58:35.126 ? W/ADB_SERVICES: create_local_service_socket() name=shell:am broadcast -a com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION -n com.packagename.debug/.GcmBroadcastReceiver --es data.alert foo
01-13 11:58:35.126 ? W/ADB_SERVICES: service_to_fd() name=shell:am broadcast -a com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION -n com.packagename.debug/.GcmBroadcastReceiver --es data.alert foo
01-13 11:58:35.127 ? W/ADB_SERVICES: LS(17153): bound to 'shell:am broadcast -a com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION -n com.packagename.debug/.GcmBroadcastReceiver --es data.alert foo' via 17
01-13 11:58:35.751 ? V/ActivityManager: Broadcast: Intent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION flg=0x10 cmp=com.packagename.debug/.GcmBroadcastReceiver (has extras) } ordered=true userid=-2 callerApp=null
```

b) When I use this command-

adb shell am broadcast -a com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION -n com.packagename/.GcmBroadcastReceiver --es "registration_id" "APA91bHk3fns3556etW8JYr0KUxJ_7GJTInDNQW23TyqKlN2nEGWcaYPC3dP6a8KmCB0VvXyfrT5jUzykzaYbvXbcYwWgcsfvsq-Q-26sBDY-Vvo1MfUkLOVf-UbsKhIWn8dU580FlzCJFvIXH9DYbit8j-OIQQ7bw"

```
01-13 12:11:32.007 ? W/ADB_SERVICES: create_local_service_socket() name=shell:am broadcast -a com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION -n com.packagename/.GcmBroadcastReceiver --es registration_id APA91bHk3fns3556etW8JYr0KUxJ_7GJTInDNQW23TyqKlN2nEGWcaYPC3dP6a8KmCB0VvXyfrT5jUzykzaYbvXbcYwWgcsfvsq-Q-26sBDY-Vvo1MfUkLOVf-UbsKhIWn8dU580FlzCJFvIXH9DYbit8j-OIQQ7bw
01-13 12:11:32.007 ? W/ADB_SERVICES: service_to_fd() name=shell:am broadcast -a com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION -n com.packagename/.GcmBroadcastReceiver --es registration_id APA91bHk3fns3556etW8JYr0KUxJ_7GJTInDNQW23TyqKlN2nEGWcaYPC3dP6a8KmCB0VvXyfrT5jUzykzaYbvXbcYwWgcsfvsq-Q-26sBDY-Vvo1MfUkLOVf-UbsKhIWn8dU580FlzCJFvIXH9DYbit8j-OIQQ7bw
01-13 12:11:32.008 ? W/ADB_SERVICES: LS(17877): bound to 'shell:am broadcast -a com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION -n com.packagename/.GcmBroadcastReceiver --es registration_id APA91bHk3fns3556etW8JYr0KUxJ_7GJTInDNQW23TyqKlN2nEGWcaYPC3dP6a8KmCB0VvXyfrT5jUzykzaYbvXbcYwWgcsfvsq-Q-26sBDY-Vvo1MfUkLOVf-UbsKhIWn8dU580FlzCJFvIXH9DYbit8j-OIQQ7bw' via 17
01-13 12:11:32.560 ? V/ActivityManager: Broadcast: Intent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION flg=0x10 cmp=com.packagename/.GcmBroadcastReceiver (has extras) } ordered=true userid=-2 callerApp=null
```

c) When I send message using another app/web:

```
01-13 12:13:08.979 ? D/PowerManagerService: acquireWakeLockInternal: lock=157179083, flags=0x1, tag="GCM_CONN", ws=WorkSource{10010 com.google.android.gms}, uid=10010, pid=5818
01-13 12:13:08.980 ? D/PowerManagerNotifier: onWakeLockAcquired: flags=1, tag="GCM_CONN", packageName=com.google.android.gms, ownerUid=10010, ownerPid=5818, workSource=WorkSource{10010 com.google.android.gms}
01-13 12:13:08.999 ? I/GCM: GCM message com.packagename.debug 0:1452667389212251%8d85449af9fd7ecd
01-13 12:13:09.035 ? D/PowerManagerService: releaseWakeLockInternal: lock=157179083 [GCM_CONN], flags=0x0, total_time=56ms
01-13 12:13:09.035 ? D/PowerManagerNotifier: onWakeLockReleased: flags=1, tag="GCM_CONN", packageName=com.google.android.gms, ownerUid=10010, ownerPid=5818, workSource=WorkSource{10010 com.google.android.gms}
01-13 12:13:09.028 ? W/GCM-DMM: broadcast intent callback: result=CANCELLED forIntent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE pkg=com.packagename.debug (has extras) }
```

Comment: try adding your Receiver in root package 
in `com.package.name`

Comment: I don't think this is any workaround for this, after all the reason MIUI added this iOS-like feature is to let user control what app can run in background and apps with no autostart permission will be completely killed if exited and memory is low.

Comment: @Meng ...and that's fine with me. My question is - once I manually restart my app, what happens to the missing chats/notifications? Is it GCM's responsibility to notify users about it or something else.

Comment: ahh, sorry I didn't read the question throughly, did you try send with delay_while_idle flag when post to GCM server?

Comment: @Meng Yes, tried delay_while_flag and few other tags too but still not working